# Returning random generator from runST

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to use a random generator inside a `runST` statement and return the generator after use so it can be used elsewhere.

If I return only a vector, the code compiles, but when adding the generator to the return statement the compilation fails. If I understand the error message correctly, it says that the function passed to the monadic fold does not modify the vector within the same state, but I can't figure out why it then compiles if I omit the random generator from the return statement.

This compiles:

```
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
import           System.Random

randVector :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> g -> VU.Vector Int
randVector n g = runST $ do
  vector <- VU.unsafeThaw (VU.enumFromN 1 n)
  let step g i = do let (j,g') = randomR (1,n) g
                    VUM.swap vector i j
                    return g'
  g' <- foldM step g [1..VUM.length vector-1]
  VU.unsafeFreeze vector
```

But this does not:

```
randVector' :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> g -> (VU.Vector Int, g)
randVector' n g = runST $ do
  vector <- VU.unsafeThaw (VU.enumFromN 1 n) :: ST s (VUM.MVector s Int)
  let step g i = do let (j,g') = randomR (1,n) g
                    VUM.swap vector i j
                    return g'
  g' <- foldM step g [1..VUM.length vector-1]
  (VU.unsafeFreeze vector, g')
```

The return statement with the frozen vector and the random generator produces the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type `ST s (VU.Vector Int, g)` with actual
>   type `(m0 (VU.Vector Int), g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the type of [`unsafeFreeze`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:unsafeFreeze).

```
unsafeFreeze :: (Unbox a, PrimMonad m) => MVector (PrimState m) a -> m (Vector a)
```

It's a monadic computation which returns `m (Vector a)`. So the expression `(VU.unsafeFreeze vector, g')` has a type of `(m (Vector Int), g)`. The type checker is telling you that it can't unify this type with the type of the `do` block, which you declared to be `ST s (Vector Int, g)`.

In order to make these types unify, we need to distribute the `m` from inside the tuple to outside; then the type checker will infer `m ~ ST s`. You need to extract the `Vector` from its monadic computation, and then pack it back up with the generator.

```
do
    ...
    v <- VU.unsafeFreeze vector
    return (v, g')
```

Answer (score 2):

`VU.unsafeFreeze vector` returns a vector in some monad (in this case `ST s`). Remember that every action has to be in the same monad in a `do` expression. Since `(VU.unsafeFreeze vector, g')` isn't of type `ST s <something>`, it does not work with `runST`.

Instead, bind the frozen vector and use `return` to return a single pair with type `ST s (VU.Vector Int, g)`:

```
  g' <- ...
  v' <- VU.unsafeFreeze vector
  return (v', g')
```